# JProfiler Offline mode for remote server

Tags: linux, offline, jprofiler, memory-profiling

I'm trying to profile a remote server running on Linux machine with JPfroler in offline mode. I created a Heap Usage Threshold trigger with actions "Save snapshot" and "Trigger heap dump". Then I added following JAVA_OPTIONS configuration to the server.

```
-agentpath:JPROFILER_DIR/bin/linux-x86/libjprofilerti.so=offline,id=SESSION_ID,config=JPROFILER_DIR/config.xml
```

My Question is how to retrieve snapshot and heap dump files generated by the trigger? Is there a location where I can look for those files in the remote server?
All answers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The heap dump is not a separate file, it will be contained in the snapshot file.

2) If you did not specify an absolute directory in the "Save snapshot" action, the files will be saved in the working directory of the profiled process.

3) The JProfiler agent will write a message to stderr when it writes the snapshot. If you don't see that message in your log file, the trigger did not run. You can also add a "Print message" action to the trigger to be more explicit.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. We are using Jetty 6 and have configured temp directory for Jetty using `-Djava.io.tmpdir` JAVA_OPTION. I found all of the JProfiler snapshots under that directory.